# Build a protege frame from nlp data

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, ontology, protege, information-extraction

I am having a few issues trying to extract information out of sentences annotated with Stanford NLP. I am new to the NLP library as welle as protege! 
This is the sentence I am parsing: 
String myTranslation = "The patient coming from the emergency room, already ventilated with garat (PS18,PEEP5,FiO2 0.6), was hospitalized. Monitorized blood pressure 77/40, heart rate 113 and undetectable SPO2. Ventilated in vacuum and then proceeded to endotracheal intubation after administration of: Midazolan 8mg, Fentanest 100, Nimbex 10mg. Tube diameter 7,5 uncuffed. Aspire secretion from TET, put in mechancial ventilation VT 450ml, FR 14, FiO2 0.6. Proceeded to Ultrasound-guided cannulation of the right internal jugular vein and asked for chest X-ray";

This is the algorithm I am using right now :

```
List<CoreMap> sentences = processor.getAnnotatedSentences(text);
    if (sentences != null && ! sentences.isEmpty()) {
        for(CoreMap sentence : sentences)
        {
            System.out.println("The first sentence is:");
            System.out.println(sentence.toShorterString())
            SemanticGraph sg = sentence.get(SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations.BasicDependenciesAnnotation.class);
            for(IndexedWord iWord: sg.vertexListSorted())
            {
                String value = iWord.originalText();
                String pos = iWord.get(CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class);
               //In the creation of an entity frame I consider only verbs and nouns
                if(!(pos.startsWith("NN")||pos.startsWith("VB")))
                    continue;
                //Here I check if the term I am analyzing is a medical term (checking with the UMLS methathesaurus)
                List<Entity> entities = matcher.getEntities(value);
                Set<String> set = null;
                //for (Ev ev: entities.get(0).getEvSet()) {
                //   set = el.getSemanticTypeSet(ev.getConceptInfo().getCUI());
                //}
                //String semanticType = set.toString();
                if(entities.isEmpty())
                    continue;
                else
                {
                   //then I collect the typed dependency
                    Collection<TypedDependency> deps = sg.typedDependencies();
                    for(TypedDependency dep: deps)
                    {
                        System.out.println(dep.toString());
                    }
                    Frame frame = new Frame(value,"",pos);
                    //And fetch the other words I think I should relate to the one I am analyizing : for instance, if I am analyzing patient, looking at the sentence, I should associate with it: emergency room, ventilated, garat(...)
                    Set<IndexedWord> descWords = sg.descendants(iWord);
                    //Here i try to merge compound words like emergency and room into a single one
                    addCompoundNamesToFrame("compound", frame, descWords, deps);
                    //addCompoundNamesToFrame("nummod", frame, descWords, deps);
                    for(IndexedWord desc : descWords)
                    {
                        if(desc.originalText().equals(value))
                            continue;
                        //"Stopword removal"
                        if(!filter(desc))
                        {
                            /*List<Entity> subEntities = matcher.getEntities(desc.word());
                            if(subEntities.isEmpty())
                                continue;*/
                        // I add the extracted informations to the frame
                            frame.addInfo(desc.originalText(), null);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Frame:"+frame);
                }

             }
        }
    }
private void addCompoundNamesToFrame(String relName, Frame frame, Set<IndexedWord> descWords, Collection<TypedDependency> deps)
{
    for(TypedDependency dep : deps)
    {
        if(dep.reln().getShortName().equals(relName))
        {
            IndexedWord d = dep.dep();
            IndexedWord g = dep.gov();
            if(!filter(g)&&!filter(d))
            {
                frame.addInfo(d.originalText()+" "+g.originalText(), null);
            }
            descWords.remove(d);
            descWords.remove(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I show you my issues using my output for the first sentence:
Frame:Term:patient,[Info:emergency room, Info:coming, Info:ventilated, Info:garat,Info:(, Info:PS18, Info:PEEP5, Info:FiO2, Info:0.6, Info:)]
Frame:Term:emergency,[Info:emergency room]

My first issue is that I would like to get garat (PS18,PEEP5,FiO2 0.6) as a single word and looking at the dependency I have no Idea how to do this.

Now, for the second sentence, I get these:
Frame:Term:intubation,[Info:endotracheal]
Frame:Term:administration,[Info:: Info:Midazolan,date:, Info:8mg, Info:Fentanest, Info:100, Info:Nimbex, Info:10mg]
Frame:Term:Fentanest,[Info:100]
Frame:Term:Nimbex,[Info:10mg]

From these dependencies:

```
 BasicDependencies=-> Ventilated/VBN (root)
  -> vacuum/NN (nmod)
    -> in/IN (case)
  -> and/CC (cc)
  -> proceeded/VBD (conj)
    -> then/RB (advmod)
    -> intubation/NN (nmod)
      -> to/TO (case)
      -> endotracheal/JJ (amod)
    -> administration/NN (nmod)
      -> after/IN (case)
      -> 8mg/NN (nmod)
        -> of/IN (case)
        -> :/: (punct)
        -> Midazolan/JJ (amod)
        -> ,/, (punct)
        -> Fentanest/NN (conj)
          -> 100/CD (nummod)
        -> ,/, (punct)
        -> Nimbex/NNP (conj)
          -> 10mg/CD (nummod)
  -> ./. (punct)
```

When what I would like to get is :
Frame:Term:intubation,[Info:endotracheal, Info:midazolan 8mg, Info: Fentantest 100, Nimbex 10mg]
So, I would like to combine the name of the drug with the dosage and see them as revelant terms of the proper word! 
Plus, the way I combine compound words works fine, but sometimes I need to combine compound words with nummod and I do not know how to reprocess the words, adding it to the set again as one single word, to add more information about it.
For instance: 
Frame:Term:pressure,[Info:blood pressure, Info:heart rate, Info:77/40,date:, Info:113, Info:and, Info:undetectable,Info:SPO2, Info:Monitorized,]
bool pressure is the combination of the two tokens bool and pressure, after i merge them to add a single information in my frame, I need to reprocess it to add the 77/40 nummod info associated with it, but don't know how!

Now, I do realize this is not trivial at all. I showed you my example so that you could understand my issues and I do not ask you to solve my problem entirely, but even a few references or examples or information could be very useful!